# XAML C# Accessing a dynamically created Xamarin Element from a different method than the creator method

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, controls

I'm trying to access a xamarin control that is dynamically created in a different method.  It seems it isn't possible to set the x:Name property of a control from the code behind C#.  I tried using the Element ID, but I can't seem to figure out how to record that then pass it to another method element.  I can't use the .FindByName (see previous note on x:Name)

Scenario:
Element is added by user action by clicking a button.  The system then asks a few questions about the input of the control via a few other UI elements.  The user fills that information out then clicks a button whose click event triggers a method to store the data in the dynamically created entry fields and pickers.  I just can't figure out how to access the values of the controls since they are in a different method.

Tried:
Naming the element
Using the elementID, but can't pass it from the creation
Creating a loop to list the elementTypes, but the element type isn't want I expected.

```
    public int ControlCount;
    public int ControlOrder;
    public int ControlIndex;
    public string newElementType;
    public Dictionary<int, List<string>> ControlsData = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    public Dictionary<int, List<string>> ControlList = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    public List<string> DetailsControls = new List<string>();

    public void textField_btn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //indexno
        ControlIndex = ControlIndex++;

        //fieldname
        Label quest1_lbl = new Label { Margin = 5 };
        quest1_lbl.Text = "Name";
        Entry quest1_ent = new Entry { Margin = 5 };
        //Guid quest1id = quest1_bx.Id;

        //log entry?
        Label quest2_lbl = new Label { Margin = 5 };
        quest2_lbl.Text = "Log Entry";
        Picker quest2_cb = new Picker { Margin = 5 };
        var answer2_list = new List<string>();
        answer2_list.Add("Yes");
        answer2_list.Add("No");
        quest2_cb.ItemsSource = answer2_list;
        //Guid quest2id = quest2_bx.Id;

        //entry type?
        Label quest3_lbl = new Label { Margin = 5 };
        quest3_lbl.Text = "Numeric";
        Picker quest3_cb = new Picker { Margin = 5 };
        var answer3_list = new List<string>();
        quest2_cb.ItemsSource = answer2_list;
        //Guid quest3id = quest3_bx.Id;

        //add components to the question grid
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest1_lbl);
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest1_ent);
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest2_lbl);
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest2_cb);
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest3_lbl);
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(quest3_cb);
        Previewer.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
        ComponentMenu.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
        DetailsMenu.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);



        Button AddComponent = new Button { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#a2e0ba"), TextColor = Color.White };
        AddComponent.Text = "Create";
        AddComponent.HeightRequest = 40;
        AddComponent.Margin = 5;
        AddComponent.FontSize = 20;
        DetailsMenuCol.Children.Add(AddComponent);
        AddComponent.Clicked += new EventHandler(this.addTextField_btn_clicked);
        



    }

    void addTextField_btn_clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (var child in DetailsMenuCol.Children.Reverse())
        {
            var childType = child.GetType().GetElementType();
            var childTypeName = child.GetType().Name;

            if (childType is EntryCell)
            {

            }

        }

    }
```

The last method is really just where I'm trying to return the data from the controls that were created in the first method.  I would like the solution to be cross-platform, but am open to other solutions if necessary.

Comment: You reference them the way you would any C# object - by assigning a reference to them.  However, all of your reference variables are locally scoped and will not be accessible outside of the method where they are created.  You need to use class level variables that will be accessible everywhere in the class.  This is basic C#, not Xamarin specific.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the label at class level and you can access it in the whole class:

```
public Label quest1_lbl { get; set; }
public void textField_btn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    //fieldname
    quest1_lbl = new Label { Margin = 5 };
    quest1_lbl.Text = "Name";
    Entry quest1_ent = new Entry { Margin = 5 };
    //Guid quest1id = quest1_bx.Id;

}

void addTextField_btn_clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    quest1_lbl.Text...
}
```

Or give a label a specific id and query it with the id:

```
public void textField_btn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    //fieldname
    Label quest1_lbl = new Label { Margin = 5 };
    quest1_lbl.Text = "Name";
    quest1_lbl.ClassId = "MyLabel";

}



   void addTextField_btn_clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var child in DetailsMenuCol.Children.Reverse())
    {
        if (child is Label)
        {
            Label myLabel = child as Label;

            if (myLabel.ClassId == "MyLabel")
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the second item you posted and it’s close I believe, as it isn’t returning a declaration error as a similar section of code was that I tried.  However, the elements are never recognized.  I do get a warning that says the “childTypes” will never be Entry or Picker (or for that matter Label, I tried it just to be sure as there are a couple labels produced).  I checked to confirm I was looping through the correct column in the grid and I was.  The entries and pickers do appear in the column called by the app elsewhere when ran, but it’s not recognizing them as any of the ElementType’s.

Comment: User action creates the label and entries and they can be any number of different types, quantities, and combinations.  As such, I’m not sure I could create them all at the class level for reference later.  I like the second option because it allows the user to create any number of objects and the system can still recognize them.  But if I’m thinking about it incorrectly and it is possible let me know and I’ll try the first option.

Comment: @Notalotofthought Please have a try with my updated answer.